# How to obtain reference to Jersey service from within Jetty

Tags: web-services, servlets, jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

i add a webservice 'MyService' to my context:

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
ServletHolder myServlet = context.addServlet( org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/service/*");
jerseyTaskServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
MyService.class.getCanonicalName());
```

So now i need to call a method (it's not a method from the web api, just a normal java method ) from `MyService`, this method is not static. I need a reference to an instance of MyService.

How can i acces the instance of MyService in this context?

Comment: You might need to do that during your context startup, let jersey start itself, then initialize within the Servlet context/container, then your code initializes itself.

Comment: ok i can do something like: `context.getServletHandler().getServlets()[1].initialize()` but how do i get the instance of MyService from the servlet?

Comment: also `context.getServletHandler().getServlets()[1].getServletInstance()` is always returning me `null`